# Waxsim Xcode 4.4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, kif-framework

I have been using Cruise Control, KIF, and Waxsim to test my iOS applications.  Recently, I upgraded to Xcode 4.4 and noticed WaxSim no longer runs.  I am getting this error which makes me believe that the iPhoneSimulator private framework got moved.  Any ideas on how to get WaxSim up and running again?

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DevToolsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsFoundation
Referenced from: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that you have to re-build and re-install WaxSim everytime the SDK is updated. Run

```
WaxSim -a
```

to see the list of available SDKs. If yours is not listed there then re-build and re-install WaxSim using the following command.

```
sudo xcodebuild install DSTROOT=/
```

I also got WaxSim from the following repo :

https://github.com/jonathanpenn/WaxSim

who fixed a couple of things - like accessing stuff from the Xcode.app instead of /Developer

Answer (score 4):

Yes, previously Xcode was under `/Developer`, now that it is distributed through the Mac App Store, it is under `/Applications`.  Sadly WaxSim doesn't seem to be well maintained or patched in this regard, so you need to fool it into thinking the libraries/frameworks are in the right place.

I did the symlinks here:

http://www.leonardoborges.com/writings/2012/05/03/build-automation-with-xcode-4-dot-3-kif-and-jenkins/

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ /Developer
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsCParsing.framework /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsFoundation.framework /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsInterface.framework /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsKit.framework /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsRemoteClient.framework /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsSupport.framework /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
```

Sorry to Leonardo for the bold copy/paste from his site, but I guess that's what SO wants -- the answers here as well as a link.

Comment: Yea, I actually have those from the move from XCode 4.2 to 4.3.  I have decided to move over to ios-sim.  Unfortunately, I am also having related problems with that.

Comment: Thx for the tip @JamesPaolantonio, ios-sim is working fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than set up symlinks, i did the following:

Open the project in xcode, gone into the target settings, and edited 'Runpath Search Paths' to be the following:

```
/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks
```

Also remove and re-add the QTKit and AppKit frameworks so that it can find them with your version of Xcode.